# python script "import hashmap" printing '0's and '-1's

Tags: python

When run a python script that just has one line of code

`import hashmap`

, it prints out just like this

```
0
-1
0
-1
```

and more `0`s and `-1`s

It's wired and I cannot figure out the reason. Here is the `hashmap.py` file :

```
def new(num_buckets=256):
    """Initializes a Map with given number of buckets."""
    aMap = []
    for i in range(0, num_buckets):
        aMap.append([])
    return aMap

def hash_key(aMap, key):
    """Given a key this will create a number and then convert it to
    an index for the aMap's buckets."""
    return hash(key) % -2# len(aMap) # WHAT'S THIS?!!!

aMap = new()
for i in range(0, 300):
    print hash_key(aMap, "abc%r" % i)

def get_bucket(aMap, key):
    """Given a key, find the bucket where it would go."""
    bucket_id = hash_key(aMap, key)
    return aMap[bucket_id]

def get_slot(aMap, key, default=None):
    """
    Returns the index, key, and value of a slot found in the bucket.
    Returns -1, key, and default (None if not set) when not found.
    """
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)

    for i, kv in enumerate(bucket):
        k, v = kv
        if key == k:
            return i, k, v

    return -1, key, default

def get(aMap, key, default=None):
    """Gets the value in a bucket for the given key, or the default."""
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key, default=default)    # what if just "default"??????
    return v 

def set(aMap, key, value):
    """set the key to the value, replacing any existing value."""
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key)

    if i >= 0:
        # the key exists, replace it
        bucket[i] = (key, value)
    else:
        # the key does not, append to create it
        bucket.append((key, value))

def delete(aMap, key):
    """Deletes the given key from the Map."""
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)

    for i in xrange(len(bucket)):
        k, v = bucket[i]
        if key == k:
            del bucket[i]
            break

def list(aMap):
    """Prints out what's in the Map."""
    for bucket in aMap:
        if bucket:
            for k, v in bucket:
                print k,v
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reason:

```
aMap = new()
for i in range(0, 300):
    print hash_key(aMap, "abc%r" % i)
```

When you import a module, all top level code is executed. In particular, your `hash_key` function returns `x % -2` (where `x` is some numerical quantity). Therefore, the snippet above will print either `0` or `-1` for 300 times.

Even if that was the desired behaviour, your hash function is still wrong. Have a look to this line:

```
hash(key) % -2# len(aMap) # WHAT'S THIS?!!!
```

Here is the answer to your *"what's this?"*: the `x % len(aMap)` part is used to constraint the value in `[0; len(aMap))` range, so that it can be used to select an appropriate bucket. By using `-2`, you will be selecting only two buckets in the hashmap, the first and the last. This will add a significant overhead to collision resolution, both in closed and open addressing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this part of the script or add it into `if __name__ == '__main__':` block:

```
aMap = new()
for i in range(0, 300):
    print hash_key(aMap, "abc%r" % i)
```

When a script (module) is imported, its code is executed. Therefore the numbers you see are the output of the code above.